# How to provide plot methods for a python class only if matplotlib is installed?

Tags: python, pandas, oop

I'm creating a class used for different data processing tasks. It's build around a pandas dataframe and I wrote a convenient method creating a specific plot only taking a column name as an argument.
Now I would like to be able to use the rest of the class in a context, where I don't have matplotlib available.

**Question:** Is there a way to only define the plot methods if matplotlib can be imported successfully?

**Things I tried:**
The first workaround was importing matplotlib within the method, but that's probably not great, because I figure every method call would have to reimport the module and any second plot method in case I need it would also have to import it.

As a second approach, I translated my question into python quite literally and it seems to work, but shouldn't there be a cleaner solution?

```py
import pandas as pd
try:
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    i_have_pyplot = True
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    i_have_pyplot = False


class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = pd.DataFrame([0, 1, 2, 3])

    if i_have_pyplot:
        def plot_data(self):
            plt.plot(self.data)
```

To make it more pythonic, I tried omitting the variable i_have_pyplot, but then the class has a non-working method probably raising a NameError which I dislike.

Comment: " probably raising a NameError which I dislike." well, it would raise an `AttributeError` if someone expect to be able to do `foo.plot_data()`. But in any case, what behavior *do you want to have*?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I meant if I simply ignored a ModuleNotFoundError during the import of pyplot and then still use plt. in the method, but I was just guessing. I think I'm looking for a transparent solution giving easily understandable Error messages, explaining that pyplot is not installed in case it isn't, but in such a way that it only prevents the plot methods and does not restrict the use of the rest of the class.